# Python Jupyter notebook ossystem / nbconvert path change

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, path, operating-system, nbconvert

Currently I have Jupiter notebooks with reports that I wish to convert into html format with the output from the notebook run (no codes). To achieve this I am using os.system and a python script (see bellow). However, this is saving the file in the same folder where my notebook is. I need it to save the html report in another directory. Any ideas on how can I modify the output file just for the run of this report?

This is my code:

```
filename = 'ReportInUse'

today = datetime.today()
cdate = today.strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
report_name = f'{filename}_{cdate}.html'
cmd = f'jupyter nbconvert --execute {filename}.ipynb --no-input --to html'
os.system(cmd) 

# If report with date currently exists, remove
if os.path.exists(report_name):
  os.remove(report_name)

# Now renaming the base report to the current date
os.system(f'mv {filename}.html {report_name}')
```

Comment: The last line in your current code block is a move command. If that works to rename the file, why won't an additional line that is a variation on the current last line move the file? Alternatively, if you haven't already, you may want to first try running the code you show when the working directory is where you want the report file saved. You'll probably need to adjust path in `filename` in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nbconvert seems to support an alternative solution, where you might [output your file to --stdout](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) and redicted it to the desired folder something like so:

```py
cmd = f'jupyter nbconvert --execute {filename}.ipynb --no-input --to html --stdout > ./path/to/dir/{report_name}.html'
os.system(cmd)
```

The `>` redirect would overwrite any (and `>>` would append to an) existing file with the same name in that location so you might not need that second os check later on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't seem to find the correct directory but I will keep trying. Your suggestion helped with the direction thanks!

Comment: the "." makes the path start from the current working directory (as a relative path), you might try without the dot and specify the absolute path instead if that helps.